# Application insights app.js and vendor.js

Tags: angularjs, azure, performance, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm implementing Application Insights to our AngularJS application.

We've already setup some kind of logic to track the loading times for API calls.
I was wondering if it is possible to track the loading times of the app.js and vendor.js files.

Do you guys know if this is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it is possible to track the loading times of the app.js and vendor.js files.

According to [ApplicationInsights-JS](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/796caa3df276975d4a5471547b136a6fcc5171b7/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/AnalyticsPlugin.ts), to get the page loading time, you can use `pageView.properties.duration` , try the following code snippet taken from the document:

```
_self.trackPageView = (pageView?: IPageViewTelemetry, customProperties?: ICustomProperties) => {
                try {
                    let inPv = pageView || {};
                    _pageViewManager.trackPageView(inPv, {...inPv.properties, ...inPv.measurements, ...customProperties});
        
                    if (_self.config.autoTrackPageVisitTime) {
                        _pageVisitTimeManager.trackPreviousPageVisit(inPv.name, inPv.uri);
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    _throwInternal(
                        eLoggingSeverity.CRITICAL,
                        _eInternalMessageId.TrackPVFailed,
                        "trackPageView failed, page view will not be collected: " + getExceptionName(e),
                        { exception: dumpObj(e) });
                }
            };
```

You can refer to [Capture and view page load times in your Azure web app with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/capture-page-load-times-application-insights/) and [PageViewPerformanceManager.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/75298bb9a72ca974c09cc40911ae3d97b74d519c/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/PageViewPerformanceManager.ts#L30)